# Moving the connection string location from app settings in umbraco

Tags: web-config, connection-string, umbraco

For some reason the connection string in umbraco web.config file is found under the appSettings tag, I would like to move it to his normal place under the  connectionStrings tag, but doing so gives me an error.
Is there any way to move it so I can use a separate file for the connection string?

the connection string now:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="data source=My-Server\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=True;persist security info=False;initial catalog=UmbracoWeb" /></appSettings>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with the connectionstrings - I have my connectionstrings in a separate config file - but if I try to do that with Umbraco 6.2.5 it just adds a new connectionstring in web.config at build time - which then breaks it! :( I can't even change the name - if I do I get an error: Can't find a connection string with the name 'umbracoDbDSN'. This all worked fine in 4. Why did it need to be broken? :(

Comment: Oh. As long as I name my connectionString umbracoDbDSN it doesn't mess with it. Which isn't even that annoying, TBH. I take back my sad faces, above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to move it?

Just reference the umbraco.dll, in your library, and use:

```
string s = umbraco.GlobalSettings.DbDSN;
```

Else I think you'll have to download the source, and change it. But then you'll have to do the fix on each update.

Comment: I am working with my partner on this site and it's pretty frustrating changing the connection string each time I commit my changes.

what do you mean by referencing the umbraco dll in my library? can you give me a code example please? Thanks

Comment: dont add web.config to ur source control:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/10/26/asp-net-web-projects-web-debug-config-amp-web-release-config.aspx

Comment: Or keep the web.config as it is, and use web.debug.config locally (set <compilation debug="true" />, use this guide to replace the appSettings : 
http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings